# Getting 500 Element is not defined error in Nuxt while rendering Editor.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to create editor using Editor.js in Nuxt project.
Seems like when I render the page the editor.js is not getting ready.

```
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';

interface IEditor {
  editor: EditorJS | null
}


export default defineComponent({
  data(): IEditor {
    return {
      editor: null
    };
  },

  methods: {
    initEditor() {
        this.editor = new EditorJS({
          holder: 'editor',
          placeholder: 'start text'
      })
    },
    destroyEditor() {
      if (this.editor) {
        this.editor.destroy();
      }
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.initEditor();
  },

  beforeUnmount() {
    this.destroyEditor();
  }
});
```

Then importing it in my page

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Editor/>
  </div>
</template>
```

when I am trying to open the url getting this error:

**500
Element is not defined**

```
at ./node_modules/@editorjs/editorjs/dist/editorjs.umd.js:1:76
at Object. (./node_modules/@editorjs/editorjs/dist/editorjs.umd.js:1:192)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create `/components/Editor.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div id="editor"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';
import Header from '@editorjs/header';

const editro = new EditorJS({
  holder: 'editor',
  autofocus: true,
  tools: {
    header: {
      class: Header,
      inlineToolbar: true
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

and use component in your `/pages/editor.vue` like this:

```
<template>
  <!-- use ClientOnly tag wrap Editor component -->
  <ClientOnly>
    <Editor />
  </ClientOnly>
</template>
```

Try this!
It's working fine with me!